# Javascripting Scope Chain Practice

Tags: javascript

I am doing the javascript practices from nodeschool.io, and I was given this code:

```js
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

(function firstFunction(){
 var b = 5, c = 6;

 (function secondFunction(){
  var b = 8;

  (function thirdFunction(){
   var a = 7, c = 9;

   (function fourthFunction(){
    var a = 1, c = 8;

   })();
  })();
 })();
})();
```

I am not able to access anything inside this so I attempted it like this:

```js
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

var start = (function firstFunction(){
 var b = 5, c = 6;

 var secondFunction = (function secondFunction(){
  var b = 8;

  (function thirdFunction(){
   var a = 7, c = 9;

   (function fourthFunction(){
    var a = 1, c = 8;

   })();
  })();

  return {
   secondFunction: secondFunction,
   printB: function () {
    return b;
   }
  }

 })();

 return {
  printC: function () {
   return c;
  }
 }

})();

console.log("a: " + a + ", b: " + start.secondFunction.printB() + ", c: " + start.printC());
```

I don't know if my approach is right but I've been stick on this all day. How would you approach this and why isn't my code working to get into secondFunction.printC?

Comment: Approach for what? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `secondFunction` is not returned from `start` ?

Comment: also why all the immediately invoked functions if you are setting them to variables?

Comment: Again, please remember that I am learning here. So in webstorm when I type start. I see that I get access to secondFunction and printB() so I thought I was doing it right. For example start.printC() does return it.

Comment: @Barmar I am learning javascript. The goal is for me to return: a: 1, b: 8, c: 6 and b is inside secondFunction so I am just trying to expose it.

Comment: This seems like a waste of time, unless you have nothing better to do than to solve brainteasers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

var start = (function firstFunction(){
  var b = 5, c = 6;
  var obj = {};

  (function secondFunction(){
    var b = 8
    obj.secondFunction = function(){
        return b;
    };
    (function thirdFunction(){
        var a = 7, c = 9;
        obj.thirdFunction = function(){
            return c;
        };
        (function fourthFunction(){
            var a = 1, c = 8;
            obj.fourthFunction = function(){
                return c;
            };
        })();
    })();
  })();
  return obj
})();

console.log ( start.secondFunction() )
```

Comment: I actually modified it a little by adding obj.firstFunction = function () { return c; }; in the firstFunction and was able to return everything here with console.log("a: " + a + ", b: " + start.secondFunction() + ", c: " + start.firstFunction());       Can you explain how you came to this? What do I need to think differently?